# Forgotten show, man wakes on a beach with people from different times

Tags: story-identification, tv

Okay, here is another question for you wonderful people.
I remember a show where a man dies and wakes up on a beach with a bunch of other people.  They are all from different periods in time, with one of them being a caveman.
All of these people try to build a society but of course conflict ensues.  One of the people who end up on this beach is a Roman emperor (I think maybe Nero or Caligula, but it could have been any of them).
One scene I remember vividly is the Roman emperor seeing a steam engine and remarking that if he had access to such technology, he would have taken over the world.
If I had to guess, I would say that it was a mid-90's American production, and it was either a movie or a mini-series.  I saw it in South Africa on the Sci-fi channel back when it knew how to spell it's name.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's [Riverworld](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0310952/) from the SciFi channel in 2003.  Based on the [book series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riverworld).  They have since [remade it](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1419950/) (now from SyFy).

[image: promo shot]

Nero is the villain.  Here he can be seen (on the right) fighting the main hero.

[image: Nero fighting]

Here is one of Nero's minions can be seen threatening Samuel Clemens here. (Thanks @Steve-O for pointing this out.)

[image: Nero minion & Twain].

Here are several people after just waking up, heading to the food dispenser (grailstone).

[image: waking/grailstone]

Other characters of note are Alice Lidell (Alice in Wonderland) and an alien caught up in the whole thing.

[image: Alice Lidell][image: alien]

Comment: Damn! You answered faster that I could turn around.  Now I have to wait 10 minutes to tick this answer.

Comment: Remembered watching it myself.

Comment: FYI: The guy threatening Sam Clemens in that screenshot is not Nero, just one of his goons.  Nero had longer, curly blond hair

Comment: @Steve-O  Thanks.  Corrected that.  Honestly, I wasn't sure since it's an odd angle and it _could_ be that actor.  Not easy to find pictures of Nero from this, honestly.